# How to set boolean type for the output

Tags: typescript

what is wrong with this code?How to fix this error :Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

```
export type Filter = <A>(f: (x: A) => A,arr: Array<A>) => A;

const filter: Filter = (f, arr) => arr.filter(f)

filter(x => x > 3 ? true : false, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Change `(x: A) => A` to `(x: A) => boolean`?

Comment: First line end should be boolean `=> A;`  `=> boolean;`

Comment: `type Filter = <A>(f: (x: A) => boolean, arr: Array<A>) => Array<A>`
Change the return type of Filter as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem like you want to filter boolean on a Array of Number?

`arr.filter(f)` which is calling Array funtion filter
so `arr.filter((x) => x > 3 )` return will not be a boolean

the type `Filter = <A>(f: (x: A) => A,arr: Array<A>) => A` is not vaild

because arr is a Array of number
and (x:number) => number
but you return a boolean by `x => x > 3 ? true : false`

Comment: you should follow Dogbert suggestion